# how to use nil with wslite soap api

Tags: grails, soap, null

Grails 2.4.4 + wslite 0.7.2.0 allows you call SOAP services thusly:

```
    def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx')
    def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate') {
        body {
            ConversionRate('xmlns':'http://www.webserviceX.NET/') {
                FromCurrency('GBP')
                ToCurrency('EUR')
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is I am calling a service which requires nil to be used, e.g.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
          xmlns:ns="bla" xmlns:i="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   :
 <ns:IdentityToken i:nil="true"></ns:IdentityToken>
```

Is there anyway to do this using the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I don't know if this is the right way, but it seems to work for our service. Below is just for illustration of the strategy to use nil:

```
def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx')
def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate') {
    body {
        ConversionRate('xmlns':'http://www.webserviceX.NET/' , 'xmlns:i': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") {
            FromCurrency("i:nil": "true", '')
            ToCurrency('EUR')
        }
    }
}
```